# Invalid group name: Group names must begin with a word character

Tags: c#, regex, exception

I received the following exception when I was using the Regex class with the regular expression: (?'named a'asdf)

```
System.ArgumentException: parsing \"(?'named a'asdf)\" - Invalid group name: Group names must begin with a word character.
```

What is the problem with my regular expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the space in the name of the capture. Remove the space and it works fine.

From the MSDN documentation:
"The string used for name must not contain any punctuation and cannot begin with a number. You can use single quotes instead of angle brackets; for example, (?'name')."

It does not matter if you use angle brackets <> or single quotes '' to indicate a group name.

Answer (score 4):

The reference for the MSDN documentation mentioned by vengafoo is here:
[Regular Expression Grouping Constructs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx)

> **`(?<name> subexpression)`**
>   Captures the matched subexpression into a group name or number name. The string used
>   for name must not contain any punctuation and cannot begin with a
>   number. **You can use single quotes instead of angle brackets; for example, (?'name').**

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your quotes around the name of the named capture group. Try the string: (?<Named>asdf)