# How to allow space in regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get the value after New : in double quote.
I can retrieve the value fine when there is no space in ListName. But if I put space between the list name (eg. NewFinancial History:\"xyz\"), it throws the error below:

> parsing "NewFinancial History:"(?[^"]*)"" - Invalid group name: Group names must begin with a word character.

it throws error at below line 
var matches = Regex.Matches(contents, regex, RegexOptions.Singleline);

Below is my code.

```
string contents = " testing NewFinancial History:\"xyz\"   ";
var keys = Regex.Matches(contents, @"New(.+?):", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value.Trim().Replace(":", "")).Distinct().ToArray();

foreach (string key in keys)
{
    List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
    string listNameKey = key;
    string regex = "" + listNameKey + ":" + "\"(?<" + listNameKey + ">[^\"]*)\"";

    var matches = Regex.Matches(contents, regex, RegexOptions.Singleline);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        if (match.Success)
        {                    
            string value = match.Groups[key].Value;
            valueList.Add(value);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you asking - error explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122951/invalid-group-name-group-names-must-begin-with-a-word-character (which you've should have  find/read by now), so what exactly you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you also use the "key" as name of the group.

The problem you have is that the group name
could not contain spaces, but you could simply create an anonymous group.

```
string contents = " testing NewFinancial History:\"xyz\"   ";
var keys = Regex.Matches(contents, @"New(.+?):", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value.Trim().Replace(":", "")).Distinct().ToArray();

foreach (string key in keys)
{
    List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
    string listNameKey = key;
    string regex = "" + listNameKey + ":" + "\"([^\"]*)\"";  //create an anonymous capture group

    var matches = Regex.Matches(contents, regex, RegexOptions.Singleline);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        if (match.Success)
        {                    
            string value = match.Groups[0].Value; //get the first group
            valueList.Add(value);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: In my above code it also searches for a New word with Space for example string contents = " testing New Financial History:\"xyz\" and NewCompany Type:"DealCloud" test "; I want to Search the keyword without space e.g from above string it should find NewCompany Type only not New Financial History.   i have used the same above method.

Comment: If you want to exclude whitespaces after New, you should use this regex instead: @"New\w(.+?):" which means that after New there is a alphanumeric character (or underscore)

Answer (score 1):

Change your foreach block to

```
List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
string listNameKey = key;

string regex = "" + listNameKey + ":" + "\"(?<" + 
        listNameKey.Replace(" ","") + ">[^\"]*)\""; // Removing spaces in the group name here
var matches = Regex.Matches(contents, regex, RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    if (match.Success)
    {                    
        string value = match.Groups[key.Replace(" ", "")].Value; // Removing spaces here
        valueList.Add(value);
    }            
}
```

The point is that group names cannot have whitespace, so you need to replace them with empty strings in places where you declare the capture group name.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/onGRbp)

Note that your `New(.+?):` regex has no whitespace to ignore, I recommend deleting `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`  flag. You can replace it with a more efficient `New([^:]+):`.

Comment: In my above code it also searches for a New word with Space for example string contents = " testing New Financial History:\"xyz\"  and NewCompanies:"DealCloud" test  "; I want to Search the keyword without space e.g from above string it should find NewCompanies only not New Financial History i have used the same above method.